# Подъем на мифический(?) перевал

Tags: семантика

Диктор раз за разом говорит:
"Подъем на мифический перевал Галибье",
"Мифическое вино Грузии" и т.д.

Понятно, что это перевод mythical. Но уж очень смешно получается.

В чем причина? Просто ложный друг переводчика или тут что-то более интересное, и слово "легендарный" переводчика не устроило?
(+)
добавляю по итогам первого обсуждения.
Здесь ожидаемый смысл очевидный. Тот или то, кто или что окружено мифами легендами. "Мифический" - явно ошибочно. Как это сказать правильно? **Прилагательное!** Кроме "легендарный"? Лучше бы - от основы "миф".
(++)
Во! Сообразил. Благодаря Людмиле. Мифологизированный. Синоним есть к нему?

Comment: Мифологизированный- сведённый к мифологии(науки о мифах), объясняемый с помощью мифологии. Синонимы есть - мифицированный,мифицировавшийся. Но разве это значение здесь? Разве перевал мифический потому что его действие объясняется с помощью мифологии? По-моему,  всё-таки просто "связанный с мифом". А с каким, посвящённый знает.

Comment: Ответ(статья, сообщение, выступление) может быть мифологизированным, а перевал нет. Мифицированный-ещё возможно-"сведённый к мифу", "превращённый в миф"

Comment: Мифицированного нет ни в одном словаре под рукой, кроме Тришина - как полный синоним "мифологизированный". Мне в обшем-то вполне подходит, только слово какое-то заумное. Поэтому и ищу синоним. А Почему перевал не может быть таковым? А вино?.... Пока писал прослушал повтор передачи про вино ))). Но еще повторят, посмотрим, на что заменят, если решаться.

Comment: Представленный в форме мифа (3 зн.); ***ставший*** им.  - (Кузнецов). Да этот перевал оброс мифами и легендами. Как и вино. Только как бы сказать... "Овеянный мифами" можно. Но не каждый же раз...

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка перевода: легенд и мифы - это сказания, предания,  из этого делается вывод: легендарный, мифический - это  синонимы, но они не синонимы.

Легендарный - породивший, вызвавший своей НЕОБЫЧНОСТЬЮ (героизмом, силой и т.п.) много легенд. Синонимы: известный, знаменитый.

Мифический - (1)овеянный преданиями, легендами, сказочный. Мифические времена, мифические богатыри (2)вымышленный, выдуманный. У этого прилагательного или прямая связь с мифом (мифические атланты), или это мифические компании, мифическая свобода и др. Нет значений "известный, знаменитый".

Comment: Vera, мне прекрасно известны значения всех слов. Вопрос в том, почему переводчик воспользовался этим вариантом. Если ошибка, то как она прошла дважды (как минимум, было больше, я не всё запомнил) в совершенно разных материалах.  И посмотрите еще, пожалуйста, что я Alex_ander'у написал. Чтобы не повторяться.

Answer (score 1):

Русский смысл этих фраз таков: тот перевал существует только в древних мифах, а рассказ идёт о посещении этих мест аргонавтами; "мифическое вино" (нет наименования сорта, испитого аргонавтами) фигурирует явно в контексте критики обманщика, утверждающего, что в Грузии есть вино - нет там никакого вина! Очередное напоминание о мифическом "грузинском стуле", оказавшемся георгианским. Типичная стратегия начинающего переводчика: перевести слова по отдельности (зафиксировав приглянувшиеся значения), затем связать их в то, что получится. Правильный же подход состоит в том, чтобы уяснить смысл сказанного и затем передать его средствами языка, на который делается перевод. Возможный исходный смысл: известнейший перевал, знаменитое грузинское вино.

Comment: Ну я же написал. На 99.99 там было mythical - легендарный, мифический. Известнейший - не то слово. Знаменитый - близко, но все-таки не совсем то. А вопрос был в том, была ли эта ошибка переводчика механической (сомневаюсь, больно уж детская), или он перевел так от безвыходности, сочтя "легендарный" не подходящим по контексту.

Comment: Слово "легендарный" не подошло бы ни к той, ни к другой фразам, независимо от общего контекста. Смысл этого русского слова подразумевает нечто общеизвестное (напр. место исторического события), в то время как отсылка к мифологии (если таков контекст) не требует широкой известности "мифа". Переводчик должен не слова с предлогами и оборотами переводить, а заложенный в текст смысл. Поэтому, если в первом предложении речь не идёт о горе из древнего мифа, то это просто плохой перевод: независимо от исходного текста, переводчик не сумел выразиться по-русски. "Безысходностью" этого не оправдать.

Comment: "Переводчик должен..." с этого места уже менторство и морализаторство. Опускаю. Давайте по сути. Мнение *"легендарный не передает"* интересно. Почему вдруг? "Перевал, о котором слагаются легенды. Вино, окруженное мифами"...

Comment: Если о чём-то (в настоящее время) слагаются мифы, это означает что вокруг этого много небылиц. А если нечто названо мифическим, это ставит под сомнение факт его существования. "Окружённое мифами" - надо так ипереводить, если в этом смысл. Возможен только внешний контекст, оправдывающий выражение "мифическое вино Грузии": если перед этим назван сорт вина, упоминавшийся в древнем мифе. Есть это в том тексте? Я предположил, что такое крайне маловероятно.

Comment: О легендах, связанных с тем перевалом, мне неизвестно - я не настолько осведомлённый читатель. Допускаю, что есть великие легенды местного значения или известные в среде альпинистов - для журнала "Ледоруб" это подошло бы, - но для меня этого недостаточно, чтобы называть тот перевал "легендарным" (как то, что на слуху, нечто овеянное славой или широко известное чем-то с ним связанным).

Comment: Нет, это обычный перевал, не альпинистский. Любой интересующийся историей "Тур де Франс" сразу поймет, о чем речь.  Футболом интересуетесь? Легендарный стадион "Уэмбли". Но тут ленедарный не вызывает не малейшего сомнения, стадион действительно оброс легендами в основном значении. Про перевал такого сказать уверено не могу, там просто множество историй. Аналогично и с грузинскими винами. Там конктекст такой, что монах рассказывает о целебных и даже чудодейственных свойствах вина, известного на территории нынешней Грузии чуть ли не с четвертого тысячелетия до н.э.

Comment: Так что легендарный тут тоже возможно, но переводчика (русскоязычного, как я понимаю) это тоже почему-то не устроило. ладно, а то движок уже ругается. Я в принципе понял вашу мысль. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Здесь смысл очевидный. Тот или то, кто или что окружено мифами легендами.
```

По-моему, не совсем так,вернее - не всегда.Мифический - относящийся к мифам,иногда "из мифов".

"Мифическое вино Грузии" - возможно понять и как "вино, упоминающееся в мифах",хотя бы в этом же "Мифе о Золотом руне". В древнегреческих источниках говорится, что во дворце у царя Эата текли настоящие винные фонтаны.

Говорят ещё о мифическом вине Болгарии. Это уж точно "из мифов".Первым богом вина был фракийский Загрей, хотя более известны его более поздние перевоплощения под именем Дионисий или Бахус. Фракийцы верили, что, отпив волшебного напитка, бог вина вселяется в их душу, и по этой причине они чувствуют себя счастливыми, начинают веселиться, петь и танцевать.

Может, именно это и имели в виду, говоря "мифическое вино"? Какая разница, чьё оно - болгарское или грузинское?

```
  "Подъем на мифический перевал Гарибье",
```

Перевала Гарибье не знаю. Есть во Франции перевал Галибье.С ним связаны мифы новой современности - о магии перевала, влекущего к себе велосипедистов, заставляющего их рисковать жизнью. Правда, здесь уместно и значение "обросший мифами" - с ним действительно связано много мифов, легенд, ничем не подтверждённых.

Так что слово употреблено правильно в обоих случаях  - именно мифический перевал и мифическое вино - "связанные с мифами"

Comment: Да, Галиьбье. Исправил. Спасибо, не заметил опечатки. Остальное - сейчас переварю. ***По-моему, не совсем так,вернее - не всегда.Мифический - относящийся к мифам,иногда "из мифов".*** - Людмила, вы не поняли этой мысли, а значит и всего вопроса. Вы даете правильное понимание слова мифический. А я о том, что подразумевалось. И по по причине несоответствия одного другому и встал вопрос. Не сомневайтесь, здесь имелось в виду что-то близкое к "легендарный"..

Comment: Вот с вином - ближе. Но разве есть у "мифический" такое значение? Тогда уж мифологический. Но боюсь, это тоже не то, что хотел сказать автор.

Comment: Мифологический - "относящийся к науке мифология и совокупности мифов". Мифический- первое и прямое значение -"относящийся к мифу,связанный с ним :"(по Ефремовой, Ушакову и словарю паронимов-)http://www.efremova.info/word/mificheskij.html - .VY4mmBvtlHw   http://paronymonline.ru/%D0%9C/224    .

Comment: Смысл вопроса я поняла, только я пытаюсь сказать, что автор мог иметь в виду именно это значение, не "легендарный" или "вымышленный", а именно связанный с мифами - вино- с греческими, а перевал с современными, почти языческими. Многие говорят о магии этого перевала, будто он живой и владеет душами его покоряющих.

Comment: И телами тоже - там же все поразбивались, переломали все кости,но всё равно едут его покорять. Разве не связано с языческими мифами о горных  богах, живущих на перевале и не отпускающих никого?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка от злоупотребления переводческим софтом, т.е. машинным переводом. Текст скармливается программе (в особо запущенном случае гуглопереводчику),  то, что получается на выходе, редактируется как построчник... если сроки горят, даже особо не вглядываясь в текст оригинала. Дело в том, что переводческая программа,  которой систематически пользуются, запоминает, как было переведено то или иное слово, и последний вариант перевода в следующий раз подставляет по умолчанию, а слова, встретившиеся в очередном тексте впервые, оставляет для перевода пользователю. Отсюда подобные ляпы. Можно предположить, что последний раз, когда данный переводчик имел дело со словом mythical, оно было употреблено именно в смысле "мифический" и это значение, зафиксированное в базе данных,   было подставлено по умолчанию в данный текст. Переводчик просмотрел, не исправил... Никогда не забуду "двигатель удушья" (choke engine) вместо "воздушная заслонка" в переводной инструкции к бензоагрегату.

Comment: Не думаю. В остальном текст весьма чистый. Ну ладно, а как переводить-то? Насчет "двигателя удушья" у меня таких перлов хватает. Я с машинным переводом с 80-х годов сталкивался.